# Unity3D database retrieves in editor but not when compiled C#. Retrieves fine in other places

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

So I have a game built in Unity3D that has database access.  Most of the URLS I have work fine in both editing and built versions.  However, one type (a panel to display the player's current score of a level and the top 3 scores of that level) works perfectly in the editor, but when I compile it to anything else (web, standalone, droid...) it the panel loads and the name displays, but nothing is retrieved.

The only difference I can think of is that this panel opens up on a mouse over a button, while the other retrievals are automatic.  Remember that when built, OTHER url retrievals work fine and display everything correctly, it's just this one panel that doesn't seem to work right.  Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

The code is in C# if that matters.  The database is MySQL with php.

Comment: HI, can you share the panel's controller code?

Comment: Sure Thing!

http://pastebin.com/kAtGabLZ

Comment: Are there default records in the database to pull for a build?

Comment: Also, Screenshots would be nice!

Comment: Did you debug.Log out the values returned ?

Comment: What do you mean by default records in the database?

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the delay.  Here are some screen shots.

Desired Result (Happens in editor): http://i.imgur.com/kxDREdO.png

Post-Build Behavior (Web, Android, etc): http://i.imgur.com/OMwnzo8.png

Answer (score 0):

**Add Missing canCallRoutine**

```
public void showScorePanal(){
    scorePanel.gameObject.SetActive (true);
    canCallCoroutine = true;
}
```

Without setting canCallCoroutine to true, you would not be guaranteed to fill the score field.

Comment: For debug pourposes, add the score.text setting line right below where you set the username.  This should tell us if you have a problem with the data or the call to set the data.

Comment: if (levelHover != null) {
            getLevelName ();
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("No level name found");
        }
 
        username.text = displayName;
  score.text = "Score: " + acc + "\nTime : " + time;
    }

Comment: I put the score.text where you said, there's definitely an issue with the call to the data in built versions.  This is very confusing and frustrating, because the high score is retrieved and displays fine in other areas of the game.  It's just this panel version that doesn't seem to want to work right.

Comment: Alright, then the next step is to look at your connection code.

Comment: For the first half (This retrieves the user's personal score for each level):
http://pastebin.com/jnsJp2PF


The second half (Retrieves the Top 3 listing):
http://pastebin.com/J4caewrN>

Comment: I'll also mention that I DO have a crossdomain XML setup on both the game's server and the database server.

Comment: This is a sample image of how the code works.  I Reduced it to just one retrieval call for the top score.  The yellow represents a part of the string that comes up when the IENumerator is called via script, the red hi-light is a simple php printf statement in the php script to retrieve the score.

http://i.imgur.com/67pJn36.png

This is a sample of what I get when I try to access it via the webpage.  The IENumerator is called fine, but nothing from the php script is displayed.

http://i.imgur.com/Q0LrGJf.png

Once again, the odd thing is that retrievals work for other parts of the code.